# Cant find Builder symbol in Stripe AddPaymentMethodActivity for Android SDK

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I get a build error when trying to load stripe activity from the Stripe Android SDK.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.stripe.android.PaymentSession;
import com.stripe.android.PaymentSessionConfig;
import com.stripe.android.PaymentSessionData;
import com.stripe.android.view.AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.Size;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;

public class HostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private PaymentSession paymentSession;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     paymentSession = new PaymentSession(
         this,
         createPaymentSessionConfig()
     );
     paymentSession.init(createPaymentSessionListener());
 }
 
 private void launchPaymentMethodsActivity() {
     new AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter(this).startForResult(
         AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter.Args.Builder()
         .setShouldAttachToCustomer(true)
         .setShouldRequirePostalCode(true)
         .build()
     );
 }

 @NonNull
 private PaymentSession.PaymentSessionListener createPaymentSessionListener() {
     return new PaymentSession.PaymentSessionListener() {
         @Override
         public void onCommunicatingStateChanged(
             boolean isCommunicating
         ) {
             // update UI, such as hiding or showing a progress bar
         }

         @Override
         public void onError(
             int errorCode,
             @NonNull String errorMessage
         ) {
             // handle error
         }

         @Override
         public void onPaymentSessionDataChanged(
             @NonNull PaymentSessionData data
         ) {
             data.getPaymentMethod();
         }
     };
 }

 @NonNull
 private PaymentSessionConfig createPaymentSessionConfig() {
     return new PaymentSessionConfig.Builder()
             .build();
 }
}
```

The resulting error is

```
error: cannot find symbol
                        AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter.Args.Builder()
                                                            ^
symbol:   method Builder()
location: class Args
```

startForResult requires "com.stripe.android.view.AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter.Args" as input and Stripe's Docs say that "the activity can be specified with Args and constructed with Args.Builder." but the Builder() constructor does not seem to be found when referenced similar to other online examples.

I do already have the customer session initialized, I just want to open the Stripe Activity for adding a new payment method. What is the proper way to start the AddPaymentMethodActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the missing "new" keyword. Updating the launchPaymentMethodsActivity method to the following solved the issue.

```
 private void launchPaymentMethodsActivity() {
     new AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter(this).startForResult(
         new AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter.Args.Builder()
         .setShouldAttachToCustomer(true)
         .setShouldRequirePostalCode(true)
         .build()
     );
 }
```